# LOAD FILE INTO TABLE...0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have tried to load a `.csv` file into mysql in many different ways. I have most recently tried

```
load data local infile 'c:\Users\...csv' into table suppression_list;
```

which works, but I'm told `0 rows affected`.

I've tried to drop the `local` but then it says the file is not found. I've tried to add `lines terminated by ...` and `fields terminated by ...` but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I've also tried saving the file as `.txt` but with no luck. `suppression_list` is just one column, `email text`.

Here is a snapshot of my data

```
覧覧覧覧覧
覧覧覧覧覧
#
# Contacts
*****@une.net.co
.australia@gmail.com
.d.yncly.d.ay@gmail.com
.dy.n.cly.d.a.y@gmail.com
.je.n.i.s.di.ken.s.o.n.1@gmail.com
.jell.yhe.a.d1.2.12@gmail.com
```

You can see it's just one column of email addresses, some of which look a little funky, I'll admit.

Comment: No warnings whatsoever. Just `Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.23 sec)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '...csv' 
INTO TABLE myTable
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 4 LINES
```

to ignore the Header lines. If you have created `mytable` like

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL
)
```

This results in

```
6 row(s) affected  Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0  0.000 sec
```

Comment: I think you may be onto something here. The query actually took a little longer when I did that, but eventually I received a similar result, `Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.36 sec)`.

Comment: ...and I'm thinking they are terminated by '\r\n'. At least when I open the file in notepad++ I can see each line ending with `CRLF`.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM suppression_list` gives you?

Comment: Oh, wait. Now it worked. `SELECT * FROM suppression_list` used to give me an empty set, but ignoring those 4 lines must have done the trick. I take it that mysql just gave up when it encountered them. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'll upvote the answer in addition to selecting it as the correct answer if you can tell me why mysql choked on those 4 lines.

Comment: might be because of the Encoding of your table. Try to Change it to utf-8, since latin is the default

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way I can encode it so that it doesn't miss any lines?

Comment: Yepp: `ALTER TABLE new_table COLLATE = utf8` This loaded all lines in my case

Comment: OK. I'm interested in doing this, but I received an error.

Comment: It says `unknown collation`.

Comment: What does `show collation` gives you? Is utf8 compiled in your Distribution?

Comment: Ah, it's `utf8_general_ci`: `ALTER TABLE new_table COLLATE = utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85502/discussion-between-matt-cremeens-and-benvorth).